# Why are these characters written to the terminal during clear?

Tags: command-line, xfce4-terminal

I recently did a `clear` on my terminal and found that the following characters were printed on a the line above:

```
[unknown character]3;J
```

I did a `clear | hexdump` to look into this and found that the following characters were printed:

```
ESC [ 3 ; J ESC [ H ESC [ 2 J
```

I tried typing these keys into my terminal, and I noticed that while the screen didn't clear, only the first J showed up. Is this a bug in the terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are what is known as an "ESCape sequence", and are the character sequence used to tell the glass keypunch that your terminal session is emulating (according to your `$TERM` environment variable) to "clear screen".

`ESC [ 3 ; J ESC [ H ESC [ 2 J` is picked depending on the value of your `TERM` environment variable. (`echo $TERM`). If `$TERM` doesn't match the kind of terminal you're using, `clear` will pick the wrong string.

What is your `$TERM`? What kind of terminal?

For example, I'm typing in to a Gnome Terminal ( <kbd>Ctrl Alt T</kbd> on my Ubuntu 14.04 graphics login) and

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-color
$ clear | od -bc
0000000 033 133 110 033 133 062 112
        033   [   H 033   [   2   J
0000007
$ clear
```

clears my screen silently.

When I'm logged in to a <kbd>Ctrl Alt F1</kbd> session, my `$TERM` starts as `"linux"`, and is set to `xterm-color` by my `~/.bashrc`

Start with reading `man tput;man terminfo`, and read the `man` pages mentioned in their `SEE ALSO` sections.

Comment: How to clear the terminal without printing those characters?