# Special characters printed on terminal after clear command

Tags: 15.04

I am using Ubuntu 15.04 and when I type `clear` command to clear the screen, I see strange characters on the terminal on scrolling up.

```
[3;J
```

Output of `echo $TERM` is `xterm`.

Here's a screenshot. Where do these characters come from and how do I remove them?

[image]

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/638952/why-are-these-characters-written-to-the-terminal-during-clear/?

Comment: @muru How do I disable it?

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `echo $TERM`

Comment: @A.B. it's `xterm`

Comment: And the output of `infocmp | grep clear`

Comment: @A.B. it's `clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=^M,`

Comment: ok, last try `clear | hexdump`

Comment: @A.B. it's `0000000 5b1b 3b33 1b4a 485b 5b1b 4a32          
000000c
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25758/discussion-between-a-b-and-ajay).